# Merging Pandas DataFrames on a new level of columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have some DataFrames with matching columns, but different indices (MultiIndex, same levels, different values).

```
cols = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
df0 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3,3), columns=cols, index=['a', 'c', 'd'])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3,3), columns=cols, index=['a', 'b', 'd'])

         foo         bar         baz
a   0.145753    0.305494    0.847635
c   0.511722    0.009868    0.053700
d   0.094677    0.935106    0.506444

         foo         bar         baz
a   0.667486    0.529557    0.733383
b   0.883774    0.420490    0.287766
d   0.406956    0.165573    0.546746
```

Each DataFrame represents an experiment; data pulled from image processing pipeline, where specific software parameters have been varied. The columns are the same, because I'm always pulling out the same metrics, but the indices are different, because I may have pushed different images though the pipeline.

I often find myself merging these DataFrames like this:

```
def merge_experiments(frames, names, exp_name='tag'):
    """Merge DataFrames on new level of columns"""

    prepared = []
    for df, name in zip(frames, names):
        _df = df.copy()
        _df[exp_name] = name

        _df = _df.set_index(exp_name, append=True)
        prepared.append(_df)

    return pd.concat(prepared).unstack(level=exp_name)

df = merge_experiments((df0, df1), ('exp00', 'exp01'))

          foo                 bar                 baz          
tag     exp00     exp01     exp00     exp01     exp00     exp01
a    0.590941  0.517771  0.190399  0.742759  0.884761  0.740587
b         NaN  0.973151       NaN  0.287167       NaN  0.505956
c    0.867419       NaN  0.357269       NaN  0.641385       NaN
d    0.676436  0.065348  0.820161  0.639484  0.005347  0.541025
```

Instead of hauling around this custom function for merging, is there a built-in way to do this in Pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is one `concat`

```
(pd.concat([df0,df1],keys=['exp00', 'exp01'],axis=1)).swaplevel(0,1,axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
Out[572]: 
        bar                 baz                 foo          
      exp00     exp01     exp00     exp01     exp00     exp01
a  0.166814  0.192251  0.804820  0.177737  0.407284  0.343585
b       NaN  0.305210       NaN  0.895246       NaN  0.670265
c  0.841093       NaN  0.710769       NaN  0.514551       NaN
d  0.432322  0.915981  0.807276  0.021481  0.366002  0.623367
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, quite easily in fact, using `concat` + `swaplevel` + `sort_index`:

```
v = pd.concat([df0, df1], keys=['exp00', 'exp11'], axis=1)
v.columns = v.columns.swaplevel(0, 1)

v.sort_index(axis=1)

        bar                 baz                 foo          
      exp00     exp11     exp00     exp11     exp00     exp11
a  0.843902  0.536313  0.248536  0.885295  0.589151  0.654772
b       NaN  0.631420       NaN  0.536034       NaN  0.819132
c  0.176537       NaN  0.498181       NaN  0.024562       NaN
d  0.668371  0.911009  0.944589  0.765258  0.081001  0.879989
```